# trying to sum numbers after finding their exponents using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to find what is the sum of numbers after finding their exponents
I am trying to print something like this:
**A exponent 1 + A exponent 2 + A exponent 3 + ... + A exponent n**

finding exponents but can't sum them

here is what I have done so far:

```
number = int(input('Enter number: '))
exponent = int(input('Enter grade of the number: '))

for i in range(1, exponent + 1):
    # print(i)
    numbers = number ** i
    # numbers = numbers + numbers
    print(numbers)
```

now I am trying to find sum of all exponent numbers, what am I missing?

Comment: So if `number=4` and `exponent=5` are we trying to get `4**1 + 4**2 + 4**3 + 4**4 + 4**5`?

Comment: yes, exactly what i am trying

Comment: Please check the geometric series. Details can be found in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = sum(number**i for i in range(1, exponent + 1))
```

Another way to achieve the same result:

```
result = 0
for i in range(1, exponent + 1):
    result += number ** i
```

By the way, this is the so called [*geometric series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and there is a mathematical closed-form formula (and this approach is the fastest that you can find):

```
result = (1 - number ** (exponent + 1)) // (1 - number) - 1
```

Comment: A pythonic answer, +1.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO Yes, but it doesn't help OP understanding what was wrong in the original code

Comment: Like it. But you prob. need to help the OP understand what's happening ... ;-)

Comment: is it possible to achieve that without build-in sum()?

Comment: @Luka [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70102211/16343464)

Comment: can you tell me how, please? I just would like to know if my code was useless or is it possible to achieve that by editing or adding anything inside it

Comment: While this is a more pythonic answer, it's harder to debug and doesn't really explain anything

Comment: @mozway I improved my answer a bit

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker what about this new version?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you are trying to print a string or the sum. I guess the latter. Then, I think you should define an 'accumulator': a variable that is initialized with value 0 and stores the sum. Like the following:

```
number = int(input('Enter number: '))
exponent = int(input('Enter grade of the number: '))

accum = 0
for i in range(1, exponent + 1):
    accum += number ** i
print(accum)
```

Comment: Let's try not to use Python built-in `sum` as the program variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a starting point (0) and to sum the value at each step:

```
number = int(input('Enter number: '))
exponent = int(input('Enter grade of the number: '))

numbers = 0
for i in range(1, exponent + 1):
    numbers += number ** i
print(numbers)
```